# Deprecation in ember verision 1.9.1. getting deprecation warining Ember.Handlebars.get() is deprecated, use Ember.makeBoundHelper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've just moved to ember 1.9.1. I have on custom helper named 'ifCond'. Am using registerHelper function to register the 'ifCond' helper. My registerHelper function looks like this.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (temp_v1, operator, temp_v2, options) {
var v1 = temp_v1, v2 = temp_v2;
v1 = Ember.HandleBars.get(this, temp_v1, options); });
```

How to write Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper() function to remove my deprecation?

Comment: Are you using the ember cli? If so you need to export the helper.

Comment: No am using EAK. version 1.9.1

Comment: The ember app kit has been deprecated in favour of [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) for quite some time now, you can't use import with the app kit.

Comment: Oh okay. So, what are the changes to be made to remove that deprecation?